# vfprintf() throws SegFault - but input is well-defined?

Tags: c

I am given the following function in a program:

```
void log(char* arg1, ...)
{
    time_t      t;
    struct tm   *tm;
    va_list     args;
    char        *fmt;
    char        curtime[TIME_STR_SIZE];
    FILE        *fd;

    va_start(args, arg1); // linux stdarg va_start req 2 args - va_lilst, parm_n


    fmt = va_arg(args, char*);

    if (lfd == NULL)
        fd = stderr;
    else
        fd = lfd;

   (void) time(&t);
   tm = localtime(&t);

   sprintf(curtime, "%02d.%02d.%d, %02d:%02d:%02d", tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_mon+1, tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);

    fprintf(fd, "%s: ", curtime);
    vfprintf(fd, arg1, args);
    fprintf(fd, "\n");
    fflush(fd);

    va_end(args);
}
```

obviously it takes a list of input parameters and writes them to a file.

But running this part of the code throws a segmentation fault which I have backtracked to vfprintf:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff4799db2 in __strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff476220d in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000401b03 in log (arg1=0x40529d "%s gestartet: PID = %d") at logging.c:73
#3  0x00000000004045d4 in main (argc=10, argv=0x7fffffffdc98) at abgleich.c:589
```

While running gdb and printing the parameters is fine:

```
(gdb) print fd
$9 = (FILE *) 0x607010
(gdb) print fmt
$10 = 0x7fffffffe1a7 "/srv/workspace/abgleich/abgleich"
(gdb) print args
$11 = {{gp_offset = 16, fp_offset = 48, overflow_arg_area = 0x7fffffffda10, reg_save_area = 0x7fffffffd950}}
```

I am curious why the segmentation fault is thrown as it looks as a well-defined input in this case.

The calling part of the function is following:

```
log("%s gestartet: PID = %d", argv[0], getpid());
```

Edit:

I have rewritten using va_copy in the following way:

```
 va_start(args, arg1); // linux stdarg va_start req 2 args - va_lilst, parm_n
 va_copy(c_args, args);

 if (lfd == NULL)
     fd = stderr;
 else
     fd = lfd;

(void) time(&t);
tm = localtime(&t);

 /* strftime(curtime, TIME_STR_SIZE, "%d.%m.%y, %H:%M:%S\0", time_ptr); */
sprintf(curtime, "%02d.%02d.%d, %02d:%02d:%02d", tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_mon+1, tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
 fprintf(fd, "%s: ", curtime);
 vfprintf(fd, arg1, c_args);
 fprintf(fd, "\n");
 fflush(fd);

 va_end(args);
```

Comment: The solution in the edited part is correct, but if that is your complete code, the copy is not needed... If was needed previously, because you used `va_arg()`, which modifies the argument. But now there's no `va_arg()` call, so `args == c_args`. `va_arg()` is usually a macro, and for the sake of this discussion you can think about it like this: `#define va_list int*` and `#define va_arg(argument, type) (type)(*argument++)` - this is of course a huge simplification, but the final effect is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `va_arg()` "function" on the `va_list` obtained from `va_start()`, the `va_list` is modified, so when passed to another function it is NOT the same as you got at the beginning. You could treat `va_list` as an pointer, and using `va_arg()` is sth like increment operator (++). You call your function like this:

```
log("%s gestartet: PID = %d", argv[0], getpid());
```

But vfprint most likely sees it like this:

```
vfprintf(fd, "%s gestartet: PID = %d", /* argv[0], <-- REMOVED */ getpid());
```

Comment: I think solution is to call a `va_copy()` before `va_arg()`.

Comment: @user694733 - Or not call `va_arg()` at all - the result is not used anyway (except for debugging and printing in GDB) (; But copying the original `va_list` will - of course - also solve the problem.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice `fmt` wasn't used.

Comment: Okay - I think I understand what you both said.
So I switched to calling vfprintf with fmt -> vfptintf(fd, fmt, args); and now it seems to work :)

Comment: @Stefan - I'm not sure I know exactly what you did, but if you just replaced `arg1` with `fmt` in your code above, then this "works" only by coincidence - you will print `argv[0]` contents, but not the result of `getpid()` (and your original format will _NOT_ be used)... Use proper solution - copy the original `va_list` with `va_copy()` (and pass unmodified copy to `vfprintf()`) or don't use `va_arg()` if you don't need to.

Comment: @FreddieChopin I have updated the question with the integration of va_copy. Would be nice if you could give feedback if I have understood you right. The call to log() is working and the correct string is written to file but not yet sure if I understood it really.